# How to open developer page with all his apps on AppGallery

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery, appgallery-connect

we can open this page on playmarket with scheme "market://dev?id=...", but on app gallery its not working. If we try open link like https://appgallery.huawei.com/#/tab/appdetailCommon%1234%7Cautomore%7Cdoublecolumncardwithstar%1234 with startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri) it open browser, not app gallery.

Answer (score 0):

The following are some common redirection scenarios for your reference.

---

1. Redirecting to the AppGallery Home Page

   Use the `action` method from `Intent` to implement the function.

```
action: com.huawei.appmarket.intent.action.MainA
```

Example:

```
public void launchAGHomePage() {
     Intent intent = new Intent("com.huawei.appmarket.intent.action.MainActivity");
     startActivity(intent);
 }
```

2. Redirecting to an App's Details Page on AppGallery

   Use the `action` method from `Intent` to implement the function.

   Method 1: by app ID

```
action:com.huawei.appmarket.appmarket.intent.action.AppDetail. withid
setPackage("com.huawei.appmarket");
name: "appId", value: "C100170981"
```

Method 2: by package name

```
action: com.huawei.appmarket.intent.action.AppDetail
setPackage("com.huawei.appmarket");
name: "APP_PACKAGENAME", value: "com.huawei.browser"
```

Note: Compared with method 2, method 1 includes additional `appmarket` and `withid` parameters from the `action` method.

3. Launching All App Stores Installed on a Device to Redirect Users to an App's Details Page in an App Store via MARKET

Pass the link whose scheme is `market://`. Android supports the standard MARKET protocol, to ensure that all app stores can be launched on Android devices. The methods are as follows:

```
Method 1: market://details?id=pkgName // for all stores
Method 2: appmarket://details?id=pkgName  // only for AppGallery
Method 3: market://com.huawei.appmarket.applink?appId=App ID" // only for AppGallery
```

Note: Method 1 is a standard method for Android devices, and is applicable to all app stores, such as Google Play and Tecent Appstore.

For more detail,pls kindly check this [link](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0203478067208130016).

Comment: your solution for opening app details, my question about opening dev page where shown all apps of that developer :(

Comment: Sorry@Ильмир Шагабиев,The team confirms that Currently there have no page you mentioned where shown all apps of that developer on the AGC.

Comment: The link above is just an example. After all, isn't it possible to programmatically send users to an AppGallery app that contains a page listing all apps from a particular developer?

Comment: sorry,AGC does not support this by now :(

Comment: You're welcome.Please feel free to contact me if you need any further help. :)